# how to update network using composer install

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am developing a nodejs client for a business network. I install the network version 100 . after I make some changes I redeployed it however the changes did not effect at least the nodejs client still logs it is connected to version 100. I increment the version 101 restart the nodejs still got 100 in the log. 
what is the procedure to update the network?

deploy command
composer network deploy -a network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s anything

oepn connection 
this.bizNetworkConnection.connect(this.CONNECTION_PROFILE_NAME, this.businessNetworkIdentifier, participantId, participantPwd)

log network identifier
LOG.info('KYC:', 'businessNetworkDefinition obtained', this.businessNetworkDefinition.getIdentifier());

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `composer network update` to update the version of an already deployed network.